# How to display a view of a particular size(not full screen) with in a view in objective-c iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view, uinavigationitem

I want to call a particular view in my xcode project. Actually, I have created a navigation based application. I have added a button in the navigation bar. Now I want, when somebody click on that button then a particular view of button list open ask for user to click a particular button.
The solution which I can think for it is to create a view and add it on the button's click.
But I am not able to find how to achieve this. Help me out?

Comment: Hello Everyone.
Thanks for your support.
I tried lots of things and finally I arrived at my destination.
I did it by creating objects of two views ie 
IBOutlet UITableView *tblView;
IBOutlet UIView *btnView;

make the second one hidden in viewDidLoad

and display it at the clicking event of the button in navigation bar.

It was easy to use and create.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        view *optionsController = [[view alloc] 
                                                   initWithNibName:@"view" 
                                                   bundle:nil];

        CGRect optionsFrame = optionsController.view.frame;
        optionsFrame.origin.x = 10;
        optionsFrame.size.width = 220;
        optionsFrame.origin.y = 123;

        //
        // For the animation, move the view up by its own height.
        //
        optionsFrame.origin.y += optionsFrame.size.height;

        optionsController.view.frame = optionsFrame;

        [self.superview addSubview:optionsController.view];


        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

        optionsFrame.origin.y -= optionsFrame.size.height;
        optionsController.view.frame = optionsFrame;

        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an **UIView** object set the **frame**  property as much you require not the full size Now create button add this as sunview to your newly created **UIView**.

Now Add your **UIView** as the subview in your main view.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to look into UIActionSheet. This sounds like a perfect use case for it.

Answer (score 0):

hey sanchit..
simply add the button either from xib or  programmaticaly and get a selector to that button (add IBAction or use[buuton addSelector:]) and in that method do something like this.

[self.view addSubview:dummyView];